# Phonegap (Cordova) - Android Webview Frozen after app is dormant for more than 20 min

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-2.0.0

I'm using Cordova 2.1.0 and seeing a problem on my Samsung Galaxy s3 (Android 4.0.1):

After the app has been put into the background for longer that 20 minutes, I fire it up again and the WebView is completely frozen. No javascript handlers fire at all, and it appears that the deviceready or resume events never fire. Again, this only happens after the app has not been used for about 20 or more minutes. I have to force a restart for things to work again. I'm wondering if anyone else has experienced this and if there are any workarounds.

--The issue appears to be similar to this Cordova jira ticket https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-1185

Answer (score 0):

After reading the jira ticket above, I upgraded to cordova 2.2.0 for Android and the issue seems fixed.